# Are there good prototyping tools for iOS?

Tags: ios, wireframing

I am looking to build an iOS (iPad) application with a very unique user interface that does not use the traditional look-and-feel of a typical iOS app. Think less like Facebook, more like Lightroom on a PC or the uniqueness of a game.

The application will be targeted to professional users and rely heavily on the drag-and-drop of graphical elements, screen scrolling and layering (think similar to Visio).

So far, I have been using screen mockup tools from Balsamiq to Visio, PowerPoint, and a few others.

I am not a professional coder so I want a tool that allows me to easily build the user experience and be somewhat functional for demonstration purposes. I do not need a final code base.

I am going to play around with Flash Builder (Flex platform) and Flash Professional to see if they do the trick, but I am worrying about these programs being too complex. I like Microsoft's Expression tools but unfortunately, these products are no longer supported.

I would really like to know if you have any good ideas for products I should try.